# How do I bind keys in emacs for a particular mode?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

[This page](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_useful_user_keybinding.html) explains how I can bind keys to certain command or a text input.

But what if I want that binding for a particular mode (say LaTeX mode) only?

To be specific, in LaTeX mode, I would like to input text `\begingroup` when
`Ctrl-{` is pressed, and input `\endgroup` when
`Ctrl-}` is pressed.

I tried the following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14410166/1337854),

```
(eval-after-load 'latex-mode 
  '(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "C-{") "\begingroup"))
(eval-after-load 'latex-mode 
  '(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "C-}") "\endgroup"))
```

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

latex-mode is an alias for tex-mode. You also need to escape the `\`
I think what you want to do is the following:

```
(eval-after-load 'tex-mode
  '(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "C-{") "\\begingroup"))
```

Comment: No, it does *not* work. Moreover, C-h k says C-{ is undefined.

Comment: If i activate latex-mode and do 'C-h k' for C-{ then i get `C-{ runs the command "\\begingroup", which is a keyboard macro.`

Comment: This is what I have done. 1) Put your code in ~/.emacs. 2) Close emacs and start with a .tex file (I could simply load the .emacs file as well). This starts LaTeX mode. 3) Now if I press C-{, emacs says C-{ is undefined. If I press C-h k C-{, I get the same message. What is it I could be missing? (I use [AucTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/), anything to do with that?)

Comment: `(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-{") "\\begingroup")`, adapted from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50981/14103 solved my problem.

Comment: eval-after-load is just there execute the 'define-key when you load your latex mode and not earlier. So you don't need it necessarily. Since I don't know AucTex my guess would be `(eval-after-load 'auctex ...`. Variables are case sensitive so, thats probably why it didn't work right away with you AucTex mode and mapping the keystroke.